# Trying to find a way to get results with dynamic querying in pymongo

Tags: pymongo

```py
results = collections.find_one( {"account_id":'4l9D6nbLLwTkNam7gpLvUzJbzE4yo3ukgRoaM' })['historical_balances']
results['2022-09-28']
```

I am trying to find the day balance based on an account. However the account can be dynamic ie.

```py
all_accounts = ['alphanumric001', 'alphanumeric002']
```

When I try to query something like `collections.find_one( {"account_id":all_accounts[0] })['historical_balances']`, I am getting an error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `results = collections.find_one( {"account_id":str(all_accounts[0]))['historical_balances'] results['2022-09-28']` maybe?

Comment: helpful will be to see the exact error in text ;)